# Does Python remember expressions evaluated in an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, if-statement

#### Background:

I am currently writing a program in Python to parse through IIS web server log files and detect 500 and 403 errors. Somewhere in the program I have the following `if` statement:

```py
if line.split(" ")[fmap["statusCode"]] == "500" or line.split(" ")[fmap["statusCode"]] == "403":
    # cool stuff happens below
```

#### Question:

What I am wondering is, would it be more efficient to split `line` and store the resulting list in a variable, since it is used twice in the `if` statement? For example, is the following code more efficient?

```py
# Is this faster and more efficient?
chunks = line.split(" ")
if chunks[fmap["statusCode"]] == "500" or chunks[fmap["statusCode"]] == "403":
    # cool stuff happens
```

*OR*, does Python remember the value of `line.split(" ")` the second time it is used in the `if` statement since it was already evaluated in the first clause of the same `if` statement? Does it recalculate `line.split(" ")` the second time, which would lower efficiency, especially for large lines?
I am especially interested on what is going on in the memory when these different `if` statements are run.

Any insight on this is appreciated!

Comment: In general this could be a good use case for the Walrus operator, but in this case you could just do `... in {"500", "403"}`

Comment: Python doesn't 'remember'/cache the calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `line.split(" ")` is not cached. You are currently recalculating that multiple times. Definitely prefer the second way.

The other options would be something like

```
if line.split(" ")[fmap["statusCode"]] in {"500", "403"}
```

Which makes it so you don't need that expression twice.